# How does SystemDateToLocalDate work in Cloud pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am aware that the function **SystemDateToLocalDate** function,

> Converts a system datetime string or object to the **user's** local time.

Which is answered here [How does SystemDatetoLocalDate work in ET?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34938/how-does-systemdatetolocaldate-work-in-et)

But I am confused on what context/how does it behave in cloudpage?

Ex:

- Assume if my user set to IST (GMT +5:30)
- If there is a cloud page which display `%%=SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())=%%`
- Assume an email is sent from Canada BU, with the link to above cloudpage.
- Would it display in IST? or Canada time?

Can anyone share any good article to understand the behaviour of this function!

Answer (score 3):

Not an explanation of the behavior but rather my findings of how the SystemDateToLocalDate function works in SFMC:

1. In the Email, when you do a Preview and Test, SystemDateToLocalDate = Account's Timezone
2. In the Email, once delivered, SystemDateToLocalDate = User's Timezone
3. In the CloudPage always SystemDateToLocalDate = User's Timezone
4. In the Script Activity always SystemDateToLocalDate = User's Timezone

I would assume, the function pulls the User's Timezone and just caches and uses that value every time it is executed with an exception of the Preview and Test environment where it is not tied up to any user.
Lastly, answering your question, the date is going to be displayed in IST.

Comment: Thanks Niko, that means. Here the USER refers to who as LOGGED IN and CREATED / PUBLISHED the cloud page?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: I have experienced about this one and `DateParse` also has the same behavior like `SystemDateToLocalDate` function